# Why is stylesheets and scripts separate from app in rails directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory-structure

I never understood why the stylesheets and scripts are outside the `/app` folder in ruby on rails. Is there benefits of housing them in the `/public` folder away from the `/app`?

Thank!
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production environment, `/app` is served by Ruby appserver, i.e mongrel, [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), etc, while `/public` is served by a webserver that is better in serving static content, i.e [nginx](http://nginx.org/). Sometimes you would also want to decouple `/public` to be served by a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), i.e [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Decoupling this two directory provides better deployment arrangement in production environment.

Comment: Great answer, you just name-dropped a bunch of stuff I've never heard of. I'll have to check them out - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `/app` folder usually contains *dynamic* data, the `/public` folder contains *static* files. This was made for caching and performance. A Web-server can output files in the `/public` folder directly to the user, without additional Ruby calls. It also can cache static files, set various headers on them and so on.